# How to check if ajax doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, laravel

I dont know what's wrong with these lines of code, in my previous insert function it works but this one it doesn't, please help me figure it out cause it takes me an hour already

```
my views(touristspot.blade.php)
<?php
foreach($data as $r){
echo "<input type='hidden' id='placeid' value='$r->placeid'>";
}
?>

<textarea id="comment"></textarea> <br>
<button type="submit" id="save" name="save">Comment</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#save").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var placeid = document.getElementById('placeid').value;
var comment = document.getElementById('comment').value;

$.ajax({
ur: "touristspot",
type: "POST",
data: {placeid:placeid,comment: comment},
success: function(data) {
//console.log(data);
}
});
});
</script>


my controller
public function addcomment(){
$details = Input::all();
$comments= new Comments;        
$comments->placeid = Input::get('placeid');
$comments->comment = Input::get('comment');
$comments->save();
return View::make('content.touristspot');
}

my routes
Route::post('touristspot','UserController@addcomment');
```

Comment: Shouldn't `ur:` be `url:`?

Comment: Ajax have failure and error functions as well, try to debug with help of these

Comment: jqueery .ajax has an `error` callback much like the `success` callback` - see the documentation at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Also it can be much shorter: `$.post("touristspot",
{"placeid":placeid,"comment": comment},function(data) { console.log(data); });`

Comment: use firbug extension to debug error cause

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**To check ajax response:**

```
$.ajax({
ur: "touristspot",
type: "POST",
data: {placeid:placeid,comment: comment},
success: function(data) {

// add these to check ajax response is null ..

    if (data == null) {
        alert("I am null");

        } else {
        alert(data);

    }

    if ($.isEmptyObject(data)) {
        alert("I am empty");
    } else {
        alert(data);
    }

},
error: function(er){
   console.error(error)
 }
})
```

});

Comment: Please clarify the full question ! what is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

Use **url** instead ur

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "touristspot", //Valid URL here
    type: "POST",
    data: {placeid:placeid,comment: comment},
    success: function(data) {
    //console.log(data);
     },
    error: function(er){
       console.error(error)
     }
    })
```

Comment: It don't really insert

Comment: URL should be point to Restful api. I dont see that you are using valid URL here.